# Not able to test SessionRegistry in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using session registry to maintain a single session.

The code is like :

```
@Component
public class AppLogout implements LogoutSuccessHandler{

@Autowired
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry

...

List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(auth.getPrincipal(), false)
```

Now whenever I am trying to write testcase for this am getting either `NullPointerException` on the 2nd line for `sessionRegistry` or not a mock exception.

Things Tried :

1. Can't do injectMocks on sessionRegistry since it's an interface

```
@Mock
SessionRegistry sg;

@InjectMocks
SessionRegistryImpl sgImpl
```

2. Using `@Mock` leads to `NullPointerException`

```
@Mock
SessionRegistry sg

Mockito.doReturn(list).when(sg).... (NullPointer on sg)
```

3. Removing the mock completely but still getting nullPointer on `sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(...)`

Actual Class :

```
@Component
public class AppLogoutHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler{
    
    @Autowired
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
    
    
    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        if(authentication != null && authentication.getDetails() != null) {
            removeAuthSession(authentication, sessionRegistry);
            request.getSession().invalidate();
        }
        
        
    }


    private void removeAuthSession(Authentication authentication, SessionRegistry sessionRegistry2) {
        
        List<SessionInformation> session= sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(authentication.getPrincipal(), false); //sessionRegistry here is giving issue
        
        if(!session.isEmpty()) {
            ....
        }
    }

}
```

Test Class (This is the latest version, Have tried the things mentioned in point 1,2 also)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AppLogoutSuccessHandlerTest {

    @MockBean
    SessionRegistry registry;
    
    @InjectMocks
    AppLogoutHandler appLogoutHandler;
    
    @org.junit.Before
    public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
    }
    
    @Test
    public void onLogoutSuccessTest() {
        //Mocked ServletRequest, Response here
        Object object = new Object();
        List<SessionInformation> informations = new ArrayList<SessionInformation>();
        //informations.add(sessionInformation); SessionInformation is created above and passed
        
        Mockito.doReturn(informations).when(registry).getAllSessions(object, false); //If i include this line it gives not a mock on when and if i doesn't then it is giving nullPointer on actual class
        
    }
}
```

Updated Test Case (This is giving null pointer on execution for line -> sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(authentication.getPrincipal(), false); )

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AppLogoutSuccessHandlerTest {

    @Mock
    SessionRegistry registry;
    
    @InjectMocks
    AppLogoutHandler appLogoutHandler;
    
    /*
     * @org.junit.Before public void setup() { MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); }
     */
    
    @Test
    public void onLogoutSuccessTest() {
        //Mocked ServletRequest, Response here
        Object object = new Object();
        List<SessionInformation> informations = new ArrayList<SessionInformation>();
        //informations.add(sessionInformation); SessionInformation is created above and passed
        
        Mockito.doReturn(informations).when(registry).getAllSessions(object, false); //If i include this line it gives not a mock on when and if i doesn't then it is giving nullPointer on actual class
        
    }
}
```

I have tried the annotation `@SpringBootTest` and without it but no luck.

Can you suggest what is going wrong with the above ways.

Comment: Option 1 is wrong. You should `@InjectMocks` on `AppLogout`. Or as you are using spring boot you should be using `@MockBean` (and assuming you write a spring boot based test), Spring Boot will take care of the autowiring.

Comment: Hi,
I tried that but getting not a mock exception on (sg).

Mockito.doReturn(list).when(sg) // This gives nullpointer with

-@Mock
SessionRegistry sg

-@InjectMocks
AppLogout applogout

Comment: Without seeing your actual test this will be impossible to answer. Using `@Mock` should be a plain Mockito test, no spring boot. When using Spring Boot for the test yo must use `@MockBean`. Trying `@Mock` with a spring boot test will do nothing, and trying to mix mockito extension and spring extension on junit5 will give interesting results. And as I stated your first sample/attempt is plain wrong, as you shouldn't use `@INjectMocks SessionRegistryImpl` (as that doesn't make any sense at all!). And 2 and 3 are basically the same as you aren't injecting the mock into anything with 2.

Comment: Added the class. Have commented few lines but those are not related to the issue.

Comment: Remove the `setup` method, ditch the `@InjectMocks` field. Also it isn't clear how you are testing this or what you want. Is it a simply unit test? THen why use `SpringBootTest` if this is an integration test you don't need the `AppLogoutHandler` only the `@MockBean` for the `SessionRegistry`. Assuming you are using JUnit5 you can ditch the `@RunWith` as well (if you are on JUnit4 leave it in).

Comment: This is just a junit4 test for this class alone. Not part of integration test

Comment: The fact that there is an `@SpringBootTest` makes this an integration test. But we still don't know how you are testing things as that is missing inside your `@Test` method. So it is unclear if you fire a `MockRequest` or directly call methods on the `AppLogoutHandler` in that method. The fact is that how you are testing actually matters on what to use.

Comment: SessionRegistry is autowired. If i ditch the injectMock am getting NullPointer during actual execution of test case. So wanted to mock the sessionRegistry object.

Comment: DIrect method call on AppLogoutHandler.

Comment: Then don't use `@SpringBootTest`, use `@Mock` ditch your setup method and use `@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)` and use an `@InjectMocks` for the `AppLogoutHandler`.

Comment: Hi, Tried but getting Argument passed to when is null on 

Mockito.doReturn(informations).when(registry).getAllSessions(object, false);

Comment: Then you diodn't use `@Mock` and/or not running with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Deinum. Was able to resolve it.

Comment: Another thing is that your matcher will never match and will return `null` from the `SessionRegistry` when called. You should use `any(), eq(false)` as matches.